# Run executable from linked file in visual studio post build command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I have a windows service executable in a separate visual studio project that I would like to start running during the post build event on a web forms project.  I have added the executable to my web project as a linked file.  I am trying to run a start command to boot up the windows service in the post build events command line, but I can't figure out how to get the file path of the executable from the linked file.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up retrieving the file path from a powershell script and placing it in a custom macro to hold the file path in the .csproj file. I just run the powershell script pre build and the exe post build using the build events command line.  A terrible hack, to be revisited another time.